# Laravel application graceful update

Tags: apache, laravel, heroku, composer-php

I'm running a laravel application using apache webserver on a ubuntu server (standard LAMP). The application is an API service under constant use - it can currently be run on a single server.

When I update my laravel application I push the new version using git and a script runs `composer install` to update the dependencies - but there is a period during the application update where incoming requests fail.

How can I temporarily pause incoming requests to my server (similar to heroku) while the laravel application is upgraded? Is there a way to gracefully pause apache (without rejecting requests) and then resume it a few seconds later after the upgrade is complete?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can simply execute the down command:

```
php artisan down
```

This will do the trick for you

and then up when you are ready

```
php artisan up
```